# How to query a munin plugin via netcat?

Tags: munin, netcat

I want to query a present Munin plugin from Nagios. As I would like to do some calculations and aggregations (the plugin reports data over a period of time) and not just look at the last values, the available plugins querying Munin data like [check_munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/browser/munin-contrib/tools/nagios/check_munin) seem unsuitable. So my idea was to get the entire `fetch` output and parse it. This however seems to present a problem for a reason I cannot understand.

If I enter `fetch my-plugin` manually after issuing `nc my-munin-node 4949`, I get the expected data output. If I try to script it, it does not work out as expected:

```
echo "fetch my-plugin" | nc my-munin-node 4949
```

just returns nothing while

```
(sleep 1 && echo "fetch my-plugin") | nc my-munin-node 4949
```

only returns the munin-node banner

```
# munin node at my-munin-node
```

without any trailing data. Running a network trace shows that the remote Munin node indeed starts sending data but is getting a `TCP RST` from the requester's end immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Netcat will close a connection if *EOF* is being received through the input file descriptor. As the `echo "string" | nc` syntax is sending the *"string"* immediately followed by *EOF*, `netcat` is tearing down the connection instantly, without accepting any data from the remote end.

A more suitable syntax would be something like

```
(echo "fetch my-plugin" && sleep 5) | nc my-munin-node 4949
```

This way, *EOF* will not be sent unless the `sleep` returns - which will take 5 seconds in this example. The time interval should be chosen long enough for `fetch my-plugin` to complete and get all data transferred.